# How do I get the value of the x-axis in qqnorm plot

Tags: r, plot, plotly, lm, quantile

I'm trying to make a norm qqplot using plotly.js with the value obtained in R.
[image: this plot is what I want to make using plotly]

I can get the y-axis values.

```
m <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Width, data=iris)
plot(m, which=2) #this plot is what I want to make using plotly
std.resi <- rstandard(m) # y-axis values
```

But, there's problem. 
I don't know how to get the x-axis values.

please advise me on this matter. 
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The x-axis contains the quantiles of a Gaussian distribution.

So, imagining that you have N points, you can obtain the values of you x-axis via:

```
a <- (1:N+1)/(N+1) #get N equally spaced values between 0 and 1
a <- a[c(-(N+1))] #remove value at 1
quant <- qnorm(a) #obtain gaussian quantiles
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: @ynjo No worries. However, if content helped, the best way to thank is upvoting/choosing the answer. Grants points and avoids spam in the comments :)

Comment: oh thank you for letting me know. I didn't know these function. have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

## Thank you so much. I got x-axis values.

```
std.resi
N <- length(std.resi)
a_2 <- 1:(N+1) / (N+1)
a_2<- a_2[c(-(N+1))]
std.resi.sort <- sort(std.resi)
quant <- qnorm(a_2)
plot(quant, std.resi.sort)
```